# Magento Sql install doesn't run but reads xml

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I got this config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <lemike_devmode>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </lemike_devmode>
</modules>

<global>
    ...
    <resources>
        <lemike_devmode_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>LeMike_DevMode</module>
                <class>LeMike_DevMode_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
            </setup>
        </lemike_devmode_setup>
    </resources>
</global>
...
```

Which is accessed because when I change  to something different then an error is thrown. So I made this Model:

```
class LeMike_DevMode_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup {}
```

And the error is gone. Just the `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` script and we're done:

```
<?php
die('hard!');
```

But after flushing my cache (via Magicento, Magento and Filesystem) and ensuring that the module is NOT in the core_resource table, it still doesn't work.

Why is my `mysql4-install-0.1.0.php` not running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Names used in the `<modules>` node are case-sensitive. This should do it:

```
:
<modules>
    <LeMike_DevMode>
        <version>0.1.0</version>
    </LeMike_DevMode>
</modules>
:
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you've places the install script inside the folder `app/code/local/LeMike/DevMode/sql/lemike_devmode_setup/`.
You can also try to clear the cache manually. Remove the contents of folder `var/cache`.
**Off topic (a bit):**
You can name your install script `install-0.1.0.php`. Starting version 1.6 there is no need for the `mysql4` prefix.